# what is the fastest/cleanest way to insert values into lists based on a string input?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I have an Java object (Object 1), which I cannot modify, with 25 ArrayLists in it.  I have to consume another object (Object 2) and place it into one of the corresponding lists of Object 1 based on a String that is found in Object 2. Each list has one and only one unique string associated with it and can be found in any Object 2.  What would be the fastest way to insert all of my Object 2s and/or the cleanest.

Right now I am just using if/else if statements to do my sorting, and I cannot use a switch statement since switch statements with String cases were only recently implemented in Java SE 7.

Edit 1: Modified the title and question. Also here is an example:

```
if ("1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.25".equals(root)) {
            physicalExamModel.addVitalSigns(observationModel);
        } else if ("1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.9.16".equals(root)) {
            physicalExamModel.addGeneralAppearanceObservations(observationModel);
        } else if ("1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.9.48".equals(root)) {
            physicalExamModel.addVisibleImplantedMedicalDevicesObservations(observationModel);
        } else if ("1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.9.17".equals(root)) {
            physicalExamModel.addIntegumentarySystemObservations(observationModel);
        } else if ("1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.9.18".equals(root)) {
            physicalExamModel.addHeadObservations(observationModel);
        } else if ("1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.9.19".equals(root)) {
            physicalExamModel.addEyeObservations(observationModel);
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your problem.

Comment: Can we see an example or something?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `Map<String, List<Foo>>`? The key is the "unique string associated with [each list]" and the value is, of course, the list itself.

Comment: Or even better, a `Map<String, TreeSet<Foo>>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm not clear that the OP actually wants each of the 25 lists sorted. He may have meant "sorted" in a different sense. Something like "I need to pick a sink for Object 2s."

Comment: I'm not clear why OP can't modify *Object 1* to begin with, and how is related the change between `if-else` with a `switch` to *improve* the algorithm (yes, that blew my mind).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Object2` instances are stored in some `Array` or `Collection` and the desired field is unique you can store them in a `Map` and then get them out as required.

Using a `TreeMap` they will even be sorted:

```
final Collection<Object2> object2s = new LinkedList<>();
final Map<String, Object2> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
for(final Object2 o2 : object2s) {
    myMap.put(o2.getField(), o2);
}

final Object2 desiredObject2 = myMap.get("SomeDesiredValue");
```

Assuming that the desired values are not unique then you can use `Collections.sort` with a custom comparator to sort a `List` of `Object2` or `Arrays.sort` to sort an `Array` by the desired field:

```
final List<Object2> object2s = new LinkedList<>();
Collections.sort(object2s, new Comparator<Object2>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object2 o1, Object2 o2) {
        return o1.getField().compareTo(o2.getField());
    }
});
```

The `Map` has the advantage of always being sorted, even if you add more `Object2` to it later but the disadvantage that the property **must** be unique. Otherwise the `Collections.sort` approach would work fine.